# Set user to role equivalent of "No role at the site" using the WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am able to successfully change the role of the user with the ID of 5 to 'subscriber' from the WordPress REST API using the following:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://foo.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/5?roles=subscriber' \
  --header 'authorization: Basic SUPERSECRETCODEISHERE' \
  --header 'content-length: 0'
```

I need to be able to set the user's role to the equivalent of "No role at the site" so that I can disable users programmatically from another site.  I have tried passing a blank value with the 'roles' key as shown below as well as things like roles=0, roles=none.  None of these worked.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://foo.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/5?roles=' \
  --header 'authorization: Basic SUPERSECRETCODEISHERE' \
  --header 'content-length: 0
```

The API returns an error such as 'The role  does not exist.'

Any help with this is appreciated.